# Simplify DynamoDB Code (JavaScript API Document Client)

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb

I'm learning DynamoDB, and I'm looking to simplify my code a bit.

I'm using node.js and the DocumentClient Class of the AWS DynamoDB JavaScript SDK.

I have this query:

```
db.query({
  TableName: "pokemon",
  KeyConditionExpression: `pk = :type and begins_with(sk, :name)`,
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ":type": "psychic",
    ":name": "mew"
  }
}, function (err, reply) {
  return console.log(err || reply)
})
```

The ExpressionAttributeValues really just plop 'psychic' and 'mew' into the KeyConditionExpression, but when I add them in manually, or with string templates, I get an error.

Like so: `KeyConditionExpression: "pk = psychic and begins_with(sk, mew)"` or `KeyConditionExpression: "pk = ${'psychic'} and begins_with(sk, ${'mew'})"` (can't use template literals here, pardon my double quotes.)

Here's the error: `ValidationException: Invalid condition in KeyConditionExpression: Multiple attribute names used in one condition`

How can I just put the query in the KeyConditionExpress and skip on the ExpressionAttributeValues?

Comment: probably needs quotes around the words `'pk = "psychic" and begins_with(sk, "mew")'`

Comment: Nope, new error now... `Invalid KeyConditionExpression: Syntax error; token: """, near: "= "psychic"`